# Problems with setting git on Sublime Text 2 "Executable '['git']' was not found in PATH."

Tags: git, settings, sublimetext2

I am a new Sublime Text 2 user and I already think it's brilliant.

Although I have some problems getting Git up and running.

I've installed the [Git](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git), but keep on getting the following window message.

[image: error message]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you ever installed Git?

Comment: Yes, that already running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please make sure you have already installed [**Git**](http://git-scm.com/). If so, you can add it to system's `Path` or change `git_command` in `Git.sublime-settings`. Please check [this plugin's document](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/wiki) for details: the **Settings** part.

> This plugin has a few settings. If you create a file called
>   Git.sublime-settings in your User package you can override them. Feel
>   free to copy the Git.sublime-settings file from the Git package
>   directory to your User package if you don't want to mess with getting
>   the initial JSON syntax right.
>
> `git_command`: a path to your git binary if it's not in the `$PATH`
>   available to Python (you'll get an error message if you need to set
>   this)
>
> (format for windows: `"git_command":
>   "c:/users/myuserdir/dev/git/bin/git.exe"`. If you have spaces in your
>   git binary's path, you may need to use the old tilda-escaped version,
>   like: `"C:/Progra~2/Git/bin/git.exe"`.)

Comment: Hi @lhuang , thank you for your answer. The git is running on my computer and this  is the Git.sublime-settings setting line for it 
"git_command": "C:\\Program Files~(x86)\\Git\bin\\git.exe"
Still, no luck

Comment: @Dom Could you please try: 1, add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` to `Path` and set `git_command` to `fase`. 2, please read the document, the path should **NOT** contain spaces. Please use the short path instead. http://superuser.com/questions/348079/how-can-i-find-the-short-path-of-a-windows-directory-file

Comment: Thanks @lhuang. First I've tried "git_command": "c:/PROGRA~2/Git/bin/git.exe" but it still did not work. And Im sorry for prob silly question (Im totally new to sublime text), but where do I need to add the path if "git_command": false ?

Comment: @Dom Just add it to your system's Path environment variable. Right click "My Computer" -> Properties -> Advanced System Setting -> Environment variables -> Add it to Path and don't forget use ";" as separator.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://docs.sublimegit.net/quickstart.html#git-executable-path), you have to open **Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeGit > Settings - User**, and write it (assuming you have the same path to git.exe, else change it). The code below works only for git 32 Bits version :

```
{
  "git_executables": {
    "git": ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe"]
  }
}
```

Tested at the moment and functional!

---

**EDIT (Added code for 64 Bits systems)**

As I needed to update git, it moved to 64-bit version. If you are also in this case, enter this :

```
{
  "git_executables": {
    "git": ["C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not less important, you can try by environment variables in Windows, follow these instructions:

- Get the folder path of the git.exe 
  `64bits: C:\Program Files\Git\bin`
  `32bits: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`
- Go to the control painel.
- Double click on system.
- Click on enviroment variables button.
- Will appear the variable enviroment window with 2 sections, **variables for the xx user** and down there **system variables**
- Select the variable **Path** in system variables and click in edit button.
- You will see a lot of paths with a semicolon after each path in variable value
  `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;`
- What you must to do is insert the github's folder path after the last  semicolon or being the first path, resulting in something like this:
  `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files\Git\bin`

  or this:
  `C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer`
- Click on OK button and close the enviroment variables window and the property system window.
- After you did that if the path is correct, restart the Sublime Text and test the git extension in Sublime Text, always that you modify the path variable is necessary to restart the Sublime Text to load the new data.
- The default path folders are for 64bits (C:\Program Files\Git\bin) and 32bits (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin)
- This was tested in Windows 8 64bits in Sublime Text 3